# Has a golf hole ever gone an entire round in a full-field event without any score worse than par?

Tags: statistics, golf, pga-tour

I noticed when watching the 2018 PGA Championship that the short par 3 3rd hole had 20 birdies and 25 pars so far during the day's play.  And that got me to wondering... has a field ever gone perfect for a round in a tournament?  And/or what's the longest streak of par or better for the field?

Comment: It's made it up to 109 players and still all clean (http://www.espn.com/golf/stats/hole/_/round/2).  That site also offers a good option for an answer, glad to say!

Comment: Success... 126 golfers in... 55 birdies, 71 pars... and that's perfection indeed.